# "User-defined type not defined" without highlighting code in VBE

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors, user-defined-types

In one of my projects I recently did refactoring and renamed quite a lot. After having completed this, everything works, all unit tests pass and yet I encounter the following.

When I perform "compile" in the VBE I do get an "User-defined type not defined" error with two strange behaviors.

1. The error does not point to a specific location in my project, i.e. nothing is highlighted
2. When I run e.g. a unit test the error does not occur when compiling after this runtime
3. As soon as I add or change some code the error does occur again

This is pretty annoying, especially as it at times does "mask" other compile time errors. I searched the web for this intensively, but did not find any hint.

Comment: Check Tools-References. Do you see any missing libs?

Comment: Corrupt VBA project - export and import everything to a new excel.

Comment: @SiddharthRout No, everything is fine with libs.

Comment: @KostasK. Unfortunately, this is not feasible, there's too much worksheet contents.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is likely due to the 'compiled' version of your VBA code being corrupted. You need to open the project using the Access.exe /decompile command line option to force Access to regenerate it. If this fixes it then you have both confirmed the issue and fixed it!

(I know this is an old post but it is the first one that came up in Google when I hit the issue so I'm leaving this here for anybody who follows in my steps :-) )

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools-Options-General and activate "Break On All Errors"
as soon as you fix the error, remember to set back this setting